# Dropbox: sync some folders in removable drive

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, sync, dropbox

I have my main dropbox folder in C:. However, I keep all my photos in a removable hard drive. Now I want  to sync these files as well, what I can think of is to create a symbolic link in the main dropbox folder pointing to the photos folder in removable hard drive. However in this case, the photos will be removed if I unplug the removable drive. If I unsync and resync the folder, it will prompt that the folder "can't be added to the computer's dropbox".

Is there a way of getting my symbolic linked folder to sync with dropbox?

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic links don't work for this scenario. Try the app Boxifier (http://www.boxifier.com) which I am the author of.

Boxifier can sync folders from your removable hard drive to Dropbox without moving them from the removable drive. In case you unplug the removable drive, your photos will not be removed from Dropbox because Boxifier has built-in protection for this scenario. When you re-connect the removable drive, Boxifier will resume syncing it with Dropbox.

[image]

The photos will start syncing.

[image]

If you remove the external drive, you can still see your pictures in Dropbox. They won't be deleted.
[image]